# Error upgrading from ExtJs3 to ExtJs4-''members is udefined" in compat mode?

Tags: version, upgrade, extjs, extjs4

I'm updating my project from Ext3.3 to Ext4.
I have added the `ext3-core-compat.js` and `ext3-compat.js` files after added the new ext4 `ext-all-debug.js` file.

I am getting a `members is udefined error` on line 3262 of ext-all-debug.js.
Which is inside the Ext.extend method which accepts 3 parameters:

```
Ext.extend = function(subclass, superclass, members)
```

i can see from the ExtJs4 documentation that Ext.extend is deprecated, however I just want to get my code working before I change all of my `Ext.extend` to `Ext.define`.

Any help guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're using the anonymous constructor syntax, like this?

```
MyClass = function(config) {
    ...
}
Ext.extend(MyClass, SomeOtherClass, {
    ...
});
```

If so, this form cannot be detected by Ext4 or the compat layer and must be updated manually to the new standard `Ext.define` syntax.  I'm not sure if this is currently mentioned in the migration documentation, and if not I'll add it.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Thats exactly what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have followed the steps in the [ExtJS 3 to 4 migration guide](http://dev.sencha.com/ext-3-to-4-migration-pack.zip), I don't think that there is much else that can be done other than to manually go through your application and make the changes. According to Sencha's [blog post](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-3-to-4-migration/) on the migration (emphasis mine):

> ## Ext JS 3 Compatibility Layer
>
> This consists of a set of files that, when included after Ext JS 4, provide overrides that will bootstrap existing Ext JS 3 code to run under Ext JS 4. The goal of this layer is not to enable your application to run unmodified under Ext JS 4 long-term. On the contrary, **you should expect to use this layer only as a temporary means of migrating fully to Ext JS 4**. The purpose of providing it is to help make the transition as swift and painless as possible. Rather than debugging obscure errors from a blank screen, you will be able to get your application back into a rendered and functional state much more quickly using the compatibility layer, making it dramatically easier to start migrating to the latest architecture.