# Converting ExtJs3 to ExtJs4?

Tags: extjs, upgrade, extjs4

This leads on from my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936439/error-upgrading-from-extjs3-to-extjs4-members-is-udefined-in-compat-mode).
I have been developing with ExtJs 3.x for about a year now and I want to migrate to ExtJs4.
I am used to coding my extJs files like below:

```
ReportsPanel = function(config){
config = config || {};

    function dummyFunction(){
       //I would usually have methods in this file also.
    }

    Ext.apply(config, {
      title: 'Reports',
      layout: 'border',
      id: 'reportsPanel',
      closable: 'true',
      items: []
    });

  ReportsPanel.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
};
Ext.extend(ReportsPanel, Ext.Panel, {
    dummy: dummyFunction//Make the dummy function available to call
});
```

And instantiating this with `new ReportsPanel()` wherever neccessary.

I have looked at many different examples of ExtJs 4 code and to be honest I'm a little confused.
I know that I should be using the `Ext.define` method. I just cant seem to get my head around it.
What should the above example converted into ExtJs4 look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could look like this:

```
Ext.define('ReportsPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    // default parameters
    title: 'Reports',
    layout: 'border',
    closable: true,

    // custom variables.
    foo: 'my var',
    bar: 'baz',

    constructor: function(config) {
        // ... do something in constructor if you need.


        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    dummyFunction: function(){
        this.foo = 'bar';
        this.bar = 'my var';
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. How would i create private variables and functions inside the Ext.define. Also in my ExtJs 3 code I have many `var = someVar` will I have to change all of them to `var: someVar` or what is the best way of doing it?

Comment: As far as I know you can't declare private variables or functions. As to your second question, you can assign variables the same way as properties and access them inside functions through the "this" property. I updated my example to demonstrate it.

Comment: You can certainly declare private variables or functions, but to do so, you wrap the Ext.define with a closure, and those private variables/functions get declared at the same closure scope as the Ext.define